how to decode the instruction data raw
for example:
here is the transaction https://solscan.io/tx/4Rh5uqvNXGydLKSRbgJX8ESsNEXdQDntHELtK7shRSUVTxuhkpitSnx2KLXt3usZ6nySBw4DXvEQVS7nV6z3ZoRV
I get the transaction detail and gain the instruction data raw, but cant decode to get the right data, please help.
the code:
from solders.pubkey import Pubkey
from construct import Int64ul, Int64sl, Struct, Bytes, Container
instruction_layout = Struct(
"user_key" / Bytes(32),
"dca_key" / Bytes(32),
"input_mint" / Bytes(32),
"output_mint" / Bytes(32),
"in_deposited" / Int64ul,
"cycle_frequency" / Int64sl,
"in_amount_per_cycle" / Int64ul,
"created_at" / Int64sl
)
def decode_instruction_data(raw_data: bytes) -> Container:
return instruction_layout.parse(raw_data)
raw_data_hex = "e445a52e51cb9a1da6ac61094d4cbd6d1bb962c8b7d4bbc0d7d88d506ae7280022aa4b469a4abbbada4d05bce4a260275a1e700c388dff95fa64a819af99e9fa2c170d16c54110f8c7d0e2b8e33af3ee00ac23fc06000000069b8857feab8184fb687f634618c035dac439dc1aeb3b5598a0f0000000000146db194d842a0b334325c1781821709d3e85b63901bd7dd4a5383bd312f3aaabb4000000000000008017b42c000000009774596600000000"
raw_data = bytes.fromhex(raw_data_hex)
decoded_data = decode_instruction_data(raw_data)
print("Decoded Data:")
print(f"user_key: {Pubkey(decoded_data.user_key)}")
print(f"dca_key: {Pubkey(decoded_data.dca_key)}")
print(f"in_deposited: {decoded_data.in_deposited}")
print(f"input_mint: {Pubkey(decoded_data.input_mint)}")
print(f"output_mint: {Pubkey(decoded_data.output_mint)}")
print(f"cycle_frequency: {decoded_data.cycle_frequency}")
print(f"in_amount_per_cycle: {decoded_data.in_amount_per_cycle}")
print(f"created_at: {decoded_data.created_at}")
